# How to print the list of fonts used in a presentation in LibreOffice Impress and / or Microsoft Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

When I copy presentations between different machines some of the characters change into Chinese characters or various different strange letters with dashes, chapos etc.

I suspect that these presentations were created on a machine very rich with "Symbol-like" fonts and most of the machines in the network lack these extra fonts.

How can I:

1. List all fonts used within the presentation
2. Mark all places any given font is used within the presentation
3. Convert the character into a vector grafic so it is displayed consistently everywhere

I need a solution both for LibreOffice as well as Microsoft Powerpoint.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that crappy technologies like PDF exist.

Comment: I understand, could you please however answer the original question?

Comment: No sir!  Sorry.. If I could have answered that question, I would have and not just made a comment.  I do understand why it is a difficult question to answer.

Comment: Do you want to keep custom font in PowerPoint? Refer to this support article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/embed-fonts-in-documents-or-presentations-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc

Comment: Some of the answers to https://superuser.com/q/1744434/939073 could also be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

I am anwering question 1: List all fonts used within the presentation

**Method 1:** With Powerpoint, Click File -> Info. Click the small arrow on the right of Properties, select Advanced Properties -> Contents

[image: IMG:]

**Method 2:**
@Señor CMasMas gave a clue about PDF although he did not elaborate. You can view/list the fonts with PDF files. Save the presentation as PDF. Open the PDF file with Acrobat Reader for example, go to File -> Properties -> Fonts. The fonts will be shown/listed there.

[image: IMG:]