# Does Microsoft Office tell me about missing fonts?

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

In my PowerPoint-presentations I used some specific fonts that I downloaded into `C:\Windows\Fonts` under Windows 10. Now my hard-drive with the `C` volume on it died. I still have the Powerpoint files (on another disk). I don't exactly remember which fonts I have installed.

What happens when I open my old PowerPoint files on the new installed Windows 11 on my new disk without my fonts?

1. Worst case: PowerPoint replaces all the missing fonts by some other fonts and the information where I used which downloaded font gets permanently lost?
2. Best case: PowerPoint tells me which fonts are missing, so that I can reinstall the missing fonts?
3. Something in-between 1. and 2.?

What will happen 1. 2. or 3.? If it is not 2.: How can I find out which fonts I had installed on my old system or at least which fonts I used in my old PowerPoint presentations?

<sub>I connected my old and my new Windows installation to my Microsoft account. Does this help anything? I use Microsoft Office 365.</sub>

Edit: The question [How to print the list of fonts used in a presentation in LibreOffice Impress and / or Microsoft Powerpoint](https://superuser.com/q/1650630/939073) is highly related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Office app treats fonts somewhat differently. As HarryC's mentioned, Word does a pretty good job of keeping you informed. PowerPoint, however, is something of a brat when it comes to missing fonts.

If a needed font is missing on the PC where you've opened a PowerPoint file, PowerPoint (actually Windows) will substitute a different font based on the closest Panose match (Panose = a system for numerically characterizing fonts based on their common characteristics; Google will tell you more if you're curious).

It WON'T warn you that a substitution has happened.
It WON'T tell you what font it's substituted.

If you select some text formatted in the missing font, and look at the font dropdown box, PPT will show you the name of the missing font.

Unless you change the font, PPT will retain the original formatting, so once you install the needed font, PPT will use it.

What fonts are needed?  You can get a somewhat accurate list by choosing the Replace Fonts dialog on the right side of the Home tab. You can also use this dialog to replace missing fonts (if you can work out which they are) with other fonts that ARE present. It will only show you available fonts on the Replace With dropdown.

It used to use icons to indicate missing fonts in the Replace dropdown but they "improved" it.

Comment: Home - Editing - Replace - Replace fonts... (In German: Start - Bearbeiten - Ersetzen -Schriftarten ersetzen) gives me a list of fonts used in the old document (but it does not tell me whcih of them are installed, but this can be checked under `C:\Windows\Fonts`. This solution is not perfect, but for PowerPoint this worked for me. The solution in https://superuser.com/a/1744446/939073 is better for Words and it offers a more convinient solution for PowerPoint that costs some money.

Answer (score 1):

**For a Word document** :

- Open the document
- Open menu *File > Options > Advanced*
- Under "Show document content" click "Font Substitution...".

This will show the missing fonts and their chosen substitution.

[image]

---

**For a PowerPoint document**

As PowerPoint doesn't have the above feature, one needs to use
workarounds.

- The [Slidewise](https://neuxpower.com/slidewise-powerpoint-add-in)
  PowerPoint add-in (commercial)
  can show this information in its own pane:

  [image]
- Use PowerPoint's "Save as PDF" to export as a PDF.
  Open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro or even the free
  Adobe Acrobat Reader and press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
  to bring up the "Document Properties" dialog, where in the Fonts tab
  you will see the substituted font and the original font (in red):

  [image]

For more information see
[Find Substituted Fonts in PowerPoint](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/textandfonts/find-substituted-fonts.html).

Comment: +1 the SlideWise suggestion. It's not free but it'll save way more time than its moderate cost.